# Node.JS Express loader:1183 Error on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, npm, error-handling, raspberry-pi, raspbian-buster

I programmed a NodeJs Express backend on my PC and when I start it, everything works fine. Now I managed to install NodeJs and npm with the same versions as on my PC, on my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Lite on it. Now I want to host my backend on it (just localy). First everything looks fine but after 5 seconds, this error appears:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /home/Raspbius/servers/humaster/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Raspbius/servers/humaster/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Raspbius/servers/humaster/server.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

I have no clue how to solve it because on my PC everything works fine with the exact same package.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, I just used bcryptjs instead of just bcrypt. Now it works fine.